# Calling background image is not working vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a template and I need to call a background-image in my scss. Calling this image using a `img` tag works perfectly fine, but as soon as I try the same in my `<style>` tags it does not work and find it anymore and gives the error `Can't resolve`.

I'm using Laravel and Vue, they are all sent to my public folder where my image is correctly located. My image is located in a file called `images` in the public folder, while my Vue is all going to my `App.js` which is inside the `js` folder in public.

What would be the correct way to call an image in Vue? Should I add an `assests` folder to my JS folder and add the image there?

Thank you for any help in advance.
**Laravel resources folder**

[image]

**Laravel public folder**

[image]

```
<template>
    <div class="hero">
         <!-- works -->
        <img src="images/home/wow.webp" alt="img">
        <div class="hero-left">
            <h1>HI</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Hero",
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

    .hero {
        height: 90vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('../images/home/wow.webp'); // Does not work

        img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Asset URLs in CSS _should_ be captured during build just like `img` tags -- it may depend on your choice of [css preprocessor and build config](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors)  though

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same path.

`images/home/wow.webp` is not the same as `../images/home/wow.webp`.

Am I missing something?